# SWIFT: Remove an item from an array of Structs

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I have an array of structs and now I want to create functionality that allows me to remove the struct by index path. I understand that structs are immutable, so any advice on how to solve this issue?

The line of code I was using to solve this was:

```
arrayOfStruct.removeAtIndex(index)
```

And this led to the error: Immutable value of type '[Struct]' only has mutating members named 'removeAtIndex'

*[clarifying edit]*

arrayOfStruct is declared within this class as:

```
var arrayOfStruct: [Struct] {
    return (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).arrayOfStruct
}
```

Comment: That most probably means that `arrayOfStruct` is declared as a *constant* with `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: I thought that was the issue as well, but it was declared as so: var arrayOfStructs = [structClass]()

Comment: Well, then a minimal (!) *self-contained* example exhibiting the problem is needed ...

Comment: https://github.com/ocedeno/MemeMe.git, the array is declared in the appDelegate file I am looking to delete an item from that array

Comment: That is not what I meant. The *question* itself must include the problematic code (reduced to its essence). Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I thought I did in the initial question.

Comment: No, because that it not self-contained. We need some lines of code which we can simply copy/paste into our Xcode to reproduce (and possibly fix) the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89019/discussion-between-octavio-antonio-cedeno-and-martin-r).

Comment: In your github, the AppDelegate.swift file has no such declaration. Have you not committed your working directory?

Comment: @OctavioAntonioCedeño: I don't want to sound rude, but I think I have now said what should be done in my opinion. Now it is your turn to update the *question* with the necessary information, instead of discussing it in a private thread.

Comment: @BaseZen sorry. I have updated it now. https://github.com/ocedeno/MemeMe.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared an accessor to your AppDelegate `memes` property as a *computed property*. Read up on the Swift spec -- computed properties are indeed read-only.

However, a read-only *class reference* can be used as a through-way to a writable structure within.

Probably you're trying to make an accessor that's not as verbose. Your shortcut will need to be:

MemeMe/MemeTableViewController.swift, line 14-16:

```
var appDel: AppDelegate {
    return (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
}
```

And then whereever you had `self.memes` before replace with `self.appDel.memes`:

MemeMe/MemeTableViewController.swift, lines 31-33:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return appDel.memes.count
}
```